# Separated elements overlooked, now combined

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Currently in the process of learning MVC and I think it's interfering with HTML code. I have just a basic navigational menu as a list and two `<li>` items seem to combine into one. Any way to make sure the two are separated when live?

```
@if ((Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToString().ToLower() != "/home/index") && (Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToString() != "/"))
{
    <nav data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="500" style="border-radius:0px; left: 0" ng-hide="sideBar" id="nav">
        <img src="~/Content/images/open.png" ng-model="sideBar" id="sideBarOpen" style="left:0px; top:0;"/>
        <div id="sideBar" style="left: -200px">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" id="navHeader"> Home </a></li>
                <li><br /></li>
                <li><a href="@Url.Action("AboutMe", "Home")" id="">About Me</a></li>
#############
                <li><a href="@Url.Action("Experience", "Home")" id=">Experience</a></li>
                <li><a href="@Url.Action("Resume", "Home")" id="">Resume</a></li>

############ These two seem to be recognized as 1 <li> and not two.

                <li><a href="@Url.Action("Contact", "Home")" id="">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <img src="/Content/images/myPic.jpg" />
                </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="sideBarBack" style="width:0%;">
    </div>
}
```

Comment: You missed `"` after first id attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youre missing a quotation mark in the `id=">` part. This is not a valid html so your wen browser tries to workaround that resulting in the two elements combined.

To fix that instead of:

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Experience", "Home")" id=">Experience</a></li>
```

use a correct tag attribute `id=""`:

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Experience", "Home")" id="">Experience</a></li>
```

Comment: Thank you. It's always the simple oversights!

Comment: I have to wait a few minutes, but I will do as soon as it allows me.